# why my onClick() method of the Button can't be useful?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is part of my html layout (with **sciter** framework):

```
 <div id="volume_micphone_slider" style="z-index:1;">
    <input id="volume_slider" class="volume_slider" type="vslider" name="p1c" max="100" value="20" buddy="p1c-buddy" />
 </div>
 <div>
     <button id="volume_show" class="volume_show"  ></button>
     <button id="micphone_show" class="micphone_show"></button>
 </div>
```

Here is my onClick() method of the Button(use **tiscript**):

```
var volume_flag=1;
function volume_ctrl()
{
   if(volume_flag)
   {                       
      $(#volume_slider).style#display ="none";
     volume_flag=0;
   }
   else
   {
      $(#volume_slider).style#display ="inline-block";
      volume_flag=1;
   }
}
$(#volume_show).onClick = function()
{
  volume_ctrl();
}
```

But this method can't be useful.Please help me to figure out my problem.Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend either using pure JavaScript or pure JQuery. You have a mix of the two, which works, but is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems in your code as explained inline

```
var volume_flag=1;
function volume_ctrl()
{
   if(volume_flag)
   {                       
      $("#volume_slider").style.display ="none"; //selector in quotes and . before style
     volume_flag=0;
   }
   else
   {
      $("#volume_slider").style.display ="inline-block";
      volume_flag=1;
   }
}
$("#volume_show").onclick = function() //small c instead of C in onclick
{
  volume_ctrl();
}
```

Comment: @theblindprophet already done, had noticed it after `save` :)

Answer (score -1):

it is pure javascript code

```
        var volume_flag = 1;
        function volume_ctrl() {
            if (volume_flag) {
                document.getElementById('volume_slider').style.display = "none";
                volume_flag = 0;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('volume_slider').style.display = "inline-block";
                volume_flag = 1;
            }
        }


        document.getElementById('volume_show').addEventListener("click", function() {
            volume_ctrl();
        })
```